# set different icon/image for shortcut ?

Tags: android, icons, shortcut

I have written a program that can create shortcut of my application in android emulator homescreen.But the problem is when i created the shortcut then it has the default android icon.
My question is how can i change the icon of the shortcut ?

I have used the following line to set the icon

```
Intent j=new Intent();
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,i);     
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,n);                                                   
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,R.drawable.icon);
j.putExtra ("duplicate", false);
j.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");   
sendBroadcast(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

The system is not in your context. You therefore need to give more details to send you icon.

see https://github.com/ldo/ShortcutCircus_Android/blob/master/src/Activity2.java

The icon is given by :

```
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(Activity2.this, R.drawable.icon)
```

Or you could decode the bitmap and use `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two way.

> putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,resId);
>
> putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);